# How to assign a tag to a floating window in Awesome WM?

Tags: awesome

I have [assigned a specific tag and screen to windows with the class "jetbrains-idea"](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/99ead4c49e0a59619611d4aab823d3388bd3f1c1/.config/awesome/rc.lua#L431-L432):

```
-- {{{ Rules
awful.rules.rules = {
    [...]
    { rule_any = { class = { "Digikam", "Gimp", "Hugin", "Inkscape", "Keepassx", "libreoffice-startcenter", "Openscad", "Simple-scan", "Sqliteman", "jetbrains-idea" } },
      properties = { tag = tags[math.min(2, screen.count())][3] } },
}
```

This only works for the main window of IDEA: **the floating "welcome window" which appears on first run just appears in whichever tag and screen was focused when it was run.** Is this fixable?

The window definitely has the same class as the main application - the following command outputs the same for either window:

```
$ xprop | grep WM_CLASS
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "sun-awt-X11-XFramePeer", "jetbrains-idea"
```

Comment: Perhaps you can check the other properties and maybe a different property could help you differentiate between them?